How to support Windows standard keyboard focus behavior without allowing unintentional actions?
In my app, when in a certain mode, if you hit the alt key and tab 3 times, you get to a certain toolbar button ("Stop"), and while that has the focus, if you hit enter, you invoke the action:

It's obfuscated because the app is proprietary, but I think you can see the issue.
0: Hitting the Alt key sets focus to the menu itself, with focus on the View menu
1: Hitting Tab sets focus to the Layout menu
2: Hitting Tab sets focus to the Help menu
3: Hitting Tab sets focus to the Stop toolbar button
4: Hitting enter runs the stop command.
My issue is that, believe it or not, people are performing this sequence by mistake, and the Stop action when you don't intend it is a costly mistake.
People are trying to perform a different editing sequence involving the Tab key, but hit Alt by mistake.
We have a bug ticket requesting that the Stop button not be able to get keyboard focus, to prevent this from happening, but I'm concerned that some other users rely on this standard, if convoluted, Windows feature to Stop, and removing it will break it for them.
We could make some other shortcut, like Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S to make it possible to use the keyboard but difficult to do it by mistake, but the above is already pretty difficult to do by mistake (and someone will eventually manage to hit Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S by mistake anyway).
We could add an "Are you SURE you want to stop?" dialog box, but that would be very annoying to the majority case where you are sure.
So generally, what's a good way to prevent an unlikely but expensive error, without creating an even worse UX problem?
